# rsync cannot exclude relative files?

Tags: rsync, filenames, path

I know the exclude option in rsync can only accept relative paths, so I though I can make workaround with `realpath --relative`.

```
$ls /usr/local/bin
cppman  demangle  e  fusuma  rem  triangle
$realpath --relative-to=$PWD /usr/local/bin/cppman
../../usr/local/bin/cppman
$rsync -va --delete --exclude=$(realpath --relative-to=$PWD /usr/local/bin/cppman) /usr/local/bin /home/user1/Desktop/transport/
created directory /home/shepherd/Desktop/transport
bin/
bin/cppman
bin/demangle
bin/e
bin/fusuma
bin/rem
bin/triangle

sent 26,689 bytes  received 189 bytes  53,756.00 bytes/sec
total size is 26,215  speedup is 0.98
```

As you can see the file `cppman` is *not* excluded, despite being relative. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclude path begins relative to your source ("root of the transfer"), not your current working dir.
Since `bin` is the directory to be transferred, the path is `/bin/cppman`:

```
rsync -va --delete --exclude=/bin/cppman /usr/local/bin /home/user1/Desktop/transport/
```

Or unanchored (without the leading `/`):

```
rsync -va --delete --exclude=bin/cppman /usr/local/bin /home/user1/Desktop/transport/
```

If you had two files `/usr/local/bin/cppman` and `/usr/local/bin/foo/bin/cppman`, the unanchored version would exclude both files while the first command excludes the first file.